# Loading Tensorflow model file not found error

Tags: python, tensorflow, path

Could you help me?

I loaded my tensorflow model like this:

```
model_path = './Model/Model'
    model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
```

But I got the error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2552, in __call__ return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2532, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args) File "c:\Users\내문서\Desktop\박민찬\@상일고 박민찬 보고서 및 자료\1학년\@ 자율교육과정, 담다프로젝트 모음\2학기\@ 2학기 자율교육과정_Machine Learning 개발과정\모델 활용 웹사이트\main.py", line 49, in upload_image      predictions = predict_image(filename) File "c:\Users\내문서\Desktop\박민찬\@상일고 박민찬 보고서 및 자료\1학년\@ 자율교육과정, 담다프로젝트 모음\2학기\@ 2학기 자율교육과정_Machine Learning 개발과정\모델 활용 웹사이트\main.py", line 31, in predict_image     model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path) File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 828, in load result = load_partial(export_dir, None, tags, options)["root"] File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 959, in load_partial ckpt_options, options, filters) File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 192, in __init__ self._restore_checkpoint() File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 527, in _restore_checkpoint load_status = saver.restore(variables_path, self._checkpoint_options) File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\checkpoint\checkpoint.py", line 1459, in restore object_graph_string = reader.get_tensor(base.OBJECT_GRAPH_PROTO_KEY) File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\py_checkpoint_reader.py", line 71, in get_tensor error_translator(e) File "C:\Users\내문서\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\py_checkpoint_reader.py", line 45, in error_translator raise errors_impl.OpError(None, None, error_message, errors_impl.UNKNOWN) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OpError`

How to solve this?
(I'm sorry for not being good at English...ㅠㅠ)

All Files' github link: https://github.com/bkmnchn/tensorflowErrorHelp

I was expecting that the model would run and tell me the result in HTMl file.

This project is to make a website that an AI shows the result which tells which rectangle it is, if a user upload an (rectangle or parallelogram or square or rhombus or trapezoid) image to the website.

Comment: Formatting of your question could be somewhat improved. Can you try that?

Comment: Kindly provide some more information, what your facing issue so that we can understand the problem to resolve.
Please Modify your code to load the model using tf.keras.models.load_model instead of tf.saved_model.load. This assumes you saved your model using model.save from a Keras model.